Mixture distributions: an intuition on why we cannot infer the number of mixture components by visual inspection
I am studying mixture models and I would like your help with this question:
Consider the distribution $\Gamma$  and assume it is a finite  mixture distribution, i.e., $\Gamma=\sum_{k=1}^K \Gamma_k \lambda_k$ with each $\lambda_k\geq 0$. Can you an intuition on why we cannot infer the number of mixture components, $K$, (or an upper bound on it) just by visual inspection (e.g., by counting how many "bells" we see in the graphical representation of the density function)?

The mixture$$\sum_{i=1}^K \frac{1}{K} \mathcal N(0,\frac{1}{i^2})$$has $K$ components and a single mode.

All continuous distributions are finite mixtures with arbitrarily large $K.$  This can be proven through explicit construction, as shown at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/486951/919 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/299765/919 for two ways to accomplish this.

Thanks. I agree with that (see also here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397076/about-a-mixture ) However, my question is about why we cannot infer $K$ just by looking at the graph of the pdf.

Well, you can certainly "infer" the number of mixture components by visual inspection. The thing is, your inference may not be any good. (Bad estimators are also estimators. ;-)

If you believe my assertion that $K$ can be arbitrarily large, then there's nothing one can infer about $K$, is there?

Those "bells" are called modes.  You might be interested to know that Normal mixtures are not necessarily multimodal.  However, there is a form of "inspection" that will work: it requires examining in detail the curvature of the log density far out into the tails, as described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/451862/919.

Firstly, it is not always the case that we will see distinct "bells" that can be associated with specific components - we may see a single bell the appears too wide or having a shoulder... an individual judgement, depending on who looks, on the aspect ration of the graph, etc. So our guess about the number of components may be wrong.
Secondly, not every distribution is amenable to a visual inspection. This surely works for a mixture of one dimensional Gaussian, but what about a distribution with hundreds of features, and possibly non-Gaussian? One example is the gut microbial data, which are known to cluster into several groups ("enterotypes"): we typically have hundreds of microbial species for every individual, which can be modeled and classified using Dirichlet Multinomial Distribution.
Finally, we often need a task to be done automatically, without involving human assistance. So we need a clear algorithm, translatable in a computer code, to perform such a task.

It's helpful here to think of counter examples.
Here's a histogram of an equal mixture of two Normal distributions with different standard deviations but similar means,
m1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=10000)
m2 = np.random.normal(0, 5, size=10000)
_ = plt.hist(0.5*m1 + 0.5*m2, bins=40)


Here's a histogram where one mixture is much smaller than the other,
m1 = np.random.normal(1, 1, size=10000)
m2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=10000)
_ = plt.hist(0.1*m1 + 0.9*m2, bins=40)


Can you spot different bells? I certainly can't.
